# ASP.NET => Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlAgilityPack'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html-agility-pack

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
```

// reference it

Produces error: ASP.NET => Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlAgilityPack' ...

HtmlAgilityPack IS referenced in my web site.

Switched from ASP.NET 2.0 to 4.0. After that, got this error. When making a console or windows forms application, all is fine, but ASP.NET build system gives me this error. I have this compile error when using HtmlAgilityPack.

No luck till today fixing this.

Comment: Well if you look at the Reference section hope it doesn't have a yellow icon there ?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, my .NET project was targeting .NET Framework 4.0 but HtmlAgilityPack.dll was build with .NET Framework 4.5.

The solution was to reference the HtmlAgilityPack.dll build with .NET Fx 4.0.

The download package for [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) offers versions for Net20, Net40, Net45 and even WinRT.

Answer (score 1):

Please set the `Copy Local` property to `True` on the Referenced DLL of HtmlAgilityPack

This will copy the dll to the output directory of your application

Comment: Where? The dll is always automatically copied to my bon-folder. I have VS 2010. It's no application, nor a web application, it's a website.

Answer (score 1):

So it worked before you changed the Framework Version to .Net 4?

If that's the case that sounds more like you also need to upgrade your dll to .Net 4.

Just get the [release from Codeplex](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/90925), in the zip there is a version of the AgilityPack for every Framework Version there is, just get the one for .Net 4 and see if that changes anything.