# Asp.Net using dll with web application project

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, class-library

i am developing an asp.net web application project.i have add a dll file with add reference command but i get error when i have  said it Using namespace_name.

Note : i tried as Asp.Net Web site.But problem is continue.i checked framework version.

C# :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using DenemePc; <-- dll file

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

ERROR:

'DenemePc' The type or namespace name could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

Comment: Could you please post the error you get ?

Answer (score 3):

I believe I have answered a similar question [ASP.NET => Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlAgilityPack'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776161/asp-net-compiler-error-message-cs0246-the-type-or-namespace-name-htmlagili)

Please set the `Copy Local` property to `True` on the Referenced DLL of DenemePc

This will copy the dll to the output directory of your application

Comment: How i set Copy Local True?i look properties.There isn't Copy Local Property.

Comment: I have found this property.It check true but i still get same error.

Comment: Error;'DenemePc' The type or namespace name could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?) Error code is CS0246.

Comment: @Bombula are you setting the Copy Local as True on DenemePc dll ?

Comment: Are all the permissions for the methods in your dll compatible with the methods calling them? If you are using "protected" instead of "public", that might be the cause.

Comment: Member's access modifiers is public.i tried on asp.net web site.There is Dll file inside BIN folder but i get CS0246 error when i declare using directive(Using ddl_name;)